# Unable to access AJAX data with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a simple form on my homepage that POST's the input to a randomly generated URL (created by `$random`) and then opens it in a new tab. That random url is running the script `run.php`

```
<form action="/run.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" id="idgen" name="idgen" value="<?php echo $random ?>">
    <input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput">
    <button type="submit" onclick="calcResult();">Go!</button>
</form>
```

I also have JavaScript functions on the homepage that use the userinput data to calculate a result. That result is (supposed to be) POST'ed to the SAME randomly generated url that the form sent to.

```
function calcResult() {
  var userinput = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
  var randomid = document.getElementById('idgen').value;

  // various functions

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://example.com/' + randomid, // same random url
            data: {result: "Hello"}
    });
```

I then add `<?php echo $_POST['result']; ?>` to the `run.php` file (the random url that the form opens is running `run.php`)

If I open the 'Network' tab (`XHR`) in Chrome Developer tools and submit the form, then this AJAX POST **does** seem to work (it sends to the same random url as the form does. The 'response' tab for that random url shows the `run.php` sourcecode, and has even replaced `<?php echo $_POST['result']; ?>` with the AJAX result `"Hello"`.

So it works succesfully in the developer tools, but it **doesn't** work in the actual random url webpage (`"Hello"` doesn't show up in the actual webpage, unlike in the developer tools).

I'm now completely lost as to what could be preventing me from accessing the AJAX result in the webpage.

Comment: The `<form>` sends your data to `run.php`, while the JavaScript function is making AJAX calls to `random-file-that-might-not-even-exist-at-all`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when you submit a form, the browser opens the page specified in the form `action` attribute - the post request will not complete before this happens - in fact, it may never start

Comment: @tyteen4a03 The form sends the data to `run.php` then (using htaccess rules and PHP code, is sent to a random url `example.com/run.php ---> example.com/abcxyz (that is running the run.php script)`. The AJAX calls to the same random url as the form was redirected to. I'm trying to access the AJAX data on the same random url as the form data is on.

Comment: you don't seem to be sending the `userinput` in your AJAX call, is this intentional?

Comment: @Pebble So how are the random URLs defined?

Comment: @upful I'm just trying to send `"Hello"` for simplicity / testing purposes. I will change that to include `userinput` once I can send that simple string succesfully.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 The random ID is generated using this hidden input field `<input type="hidden" id="idgen" name="idgen" value="<?php echo $random ?>">`, which is posted to `run.php`, then the `run.php` file redirects using `header('Location: http://example.com/'.$_POST['idgen']);`

Comment: @Pebble No, as in how does `http://example.com/<random>` come into existence? Are the files created by `run.php` or is there a rewrite rule in place?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 Yeah there's a `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /run.php?idgen=$1 [L]` in place

Comment: Are you expecting to go to (GET) `example.com/abcxyz` and see "Hello" ? You won't unless you are POSTing.

Comment: @upful Yes, that's what I'm hoping for. I am POSTing via AJAX am I not?

Comment: There is nothing to persist the data to that page (i.e. session or database)... so you are posting first, but then you are getting second, and nothing is storing the original data.

Comment: @upful I've got a MySQL database in place, but I can't access that JavaScript function result (the one sent by AJAX) in order to send it to my database. That's the primary goal. I'm trying to make JavaScript value(s) accessible in PHP (so I can add it to the database etc.).

Comment: join this room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137713/upful

Comment: @upful "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here" Unfortunately, although I can see your messages.

Comment: oh well, it seems you are trying to build an entire application and this is just one small piece... there's not enough room here to explain.

Comment: @upful Could we talk in this room https://tlk.io/stacko (just need to enter random name)?

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing is coming out of this because there is no callback function and you are probably only reloading the page. I think you should do this:

```
function calcResult(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  

  var userinput = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
  var randomid = document.getElementById('idgen').value;

  // various functions

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'http://example.com/' + randomid, // same random url
       data: {result: "Hello"},
       success: function(response){
         // callback - do what you wanna do
         alert(response);
       },
    });
}
```

UPDATE -

Considering that you want to change the page and use both userinput and randomid in run.php, you could do this in the js:

```
function calcResult(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  

  var userinput = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
  var randomid = document.getElementById('idgen').value;

  // various functions

  window.location.href = "http://example.com/run.php?randomid=" + randomid + "userinput=" + userinput;

}
```

Then, in run.php:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET) {

    $randomid = $_GET['randomid'];
    $userinput = $_GET['userinput'];

    // do what you want with both variables and return $result

    echo $result;

  } 

?>
```

Works for you?

Comment: I did originally have a callback function (which didn't work either), and read it was optional, so removed it.

Comment: But what are you trying to accomplish here - do you wanna show the response in a div for example?

Comment: Yeah, the aim was to show the AJAX result on the random url that the form opened.

Comment: SO if you want to open a new URL, why don't you use GET on the other page. No AJAX necessary. For example, direct the user to a href link `'http://example.com/run.php?randomid=' + randomId`. Then, on run.php you use $randomId = $_GET['randomId'] to get the randomId and do whatever you like.

Comment: Because in order to do the calculations in the JavaScript function, they need the `userinput`, so the form has to be submitted to get the `userinput` **then** the JavaScript function does its calculations

Comment: Can't you send both variables via GET, like `'http://example.com/run.php?randomid=' + randomId + '&userinput=' + userinput` and the use $_GET['randomId'] and $_GET['userinput'] on run.php? I'll update my answer with a suggestion